# Структуры С++ Проблема в создании

Tags: c++, структуры, char, struct

У меня возникла странная проблема при создании структуры.

```
struct Znak
{
    char surnamename[20]; 
    char znak[20]; 
    char birthday[30];
};
```

В строчке `char birthday[30];` если стоит `char` то программа компилируется нормально, а если ставлю `int` то компилятор говорит, что я ̶д̶у̶р̶а̶к̶ , и пытается считать это как `char`.) Компилировал в repl.it

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;
struct Znak
{
    char surnamename[20];
    char znak[20];

    char birthday[30];


};
int main()
{

    Znak base[100];
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0; i<n;i++) {
        cout<<"\nSurname and Name: ";
        cin>>base[i].surnamename;
        cout<<"\nZnak: ";
        cin>>base[i].znak;
        cout<<"\nBirthday: ";
        cin>>base[i].birthday;
    }
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(base[j].surnamename,base[i].surnamename)<0)
                swap(base[j].surnamename,base[i].surnamename);


        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<n;i++) {
        cout<<"Surname: "<<base[i].surnamename<<" Znak: "<<base[i].znak<<" Birthday: "<<base[i].birthday<<endl;

    }
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все просто. Ваш `birthday`, когда он `char`, понимается как `char*`, а оператор `ostream>>` для `char*` - строки в стиле C - есть.

А вот для `int*` - нет. Как вы хотите считывать *массив целых чисел* одним оператором? :)

Вот и все...

Comment: Все, я допер, спасибо!

Comment: Но есть одно но, подскажите как тогда мне массив чисел в структуру добавить

Comment: В смысле считать из `cin`? Циклом по одному числу...

Comment: Спасибо,про цикл я знаю,спасибо, я вас сначала не правильно понял.)