# Динамические структуры в c++

Tags: c++, struct

Прохожу задание в книге Алекса Эллайна. После темы указателей и ссылок в одном из проверочных заданий, он просит написать написать программу со списком контактов. Обязательное условие, что бы структура была динамической. Я написал код. Но у меня есть проблема с созданием динамической структуры. Суть моей проблемы в том, что я не могу организовать логику программы и не знаю в какой конкретно момент лучше всего объявить динамическую переменную для работы со структурой. Ниже я прикладываю свой код. В целом, код компилируется и запускается. Но, после того, как заполнить информацию о контактах и попросить их показать, то будет выведено только количество контактов, но поля будут абсолютно пустыми.
Так же, я запускал код в режиме отладки и всё равно не могу понять, в какой момент переменные из цикла, скажем так "теряются".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//Собственно, сама структура
struct People
{
    string UName;
    string UJob;
    int UPhone;
};

int pins = 0; //В этой переменной хранится информация о том, сколько в сумме имеется записей в книжке
int main() // Точка входа в программу
{
    //Сперва, мы взаимодействуем с пользователем. Спрашиваем у него, что конкретно он хочет сделать
    int action; //Переменная, которая помнит выбор пользователя
    cout << "\nWelcome to Contact app. \n\n" <<
            "1 - Show contact list.\n" <<
            "2 - Add new contact.\n\n" <<
            "Your action: ";
    cin >> action; //Реагируем на действия

    switch (action)
    {
    case 1:
        // Цикл 1. Если количество записей ноль, то пишем уведомление.
        if (pins == 0)
        {
            cout << "Contact list empty...\n";
            main();
        }
        else
            //Если есть записи, то выводим их на экран
        {
            People My_people[pins];
            for (int i = 0; i < pins; i++)
            {
                cout << "Name: " << My_people[i].UName << '\n' <<
                        "Job: " << My_people[i].UJob << '\n' <<
                        "Phone number: " << My_people[i].UPhone << '\n';
            }
            //Конец цикла 1.
        }
        main(); //Выходим в начало программы
        break;

    case 2:
        //Добавляем контакты
        //Объявляем необходимые переменные.
        int NewContact;
        string name;
        string job;
        int PN;

        //Спрашиваем, сколько будет новых контактов
        cout << "How many new contacts do you want to add?\n";
        cin >> NewContact;

        //Заполняем поля в цикле столько раз, сколько указано указано в переменной выше
        for (int i = 0; i < NewContact; i++)
        {
            cout << "Name new contact: \n";
            cin >> name;

            cout << "As whom does " << name << " work?\n";
            cin >>  job;

            cout << name << " phone number: \n";
            cin >> PN;

            pins = pins + 1; //Увеличиваем на 1 количество записей.
        }

        //Добавляем данные в динамическую структуру. Так как неизвестно сколько по факту будет новых пользователей
        People *my_people = new People[NewContact];

        //Копируем по одном введённую выше в структуру.
        for (int i = 0; i < pins; i++)
        {
            my_people[i].UName = name;
            my_people[i].UJob = job;
            my_people[i].UPhone = PN;
        }
        delete[] my_people;
            main(); //Выходим в главное меню

        break;
    }
}
```

Результат работы кода можно посмотреть по ссылке:

http://cpp.sh/8nj6k

Когда я делаю нечто подобное, без всяких ветвлений Switch (своего рода облегчённый вариант), то код работает нормально. Даже если его загнать в цикл Do While и выполнять произвольное количество раз.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct People
{
    string name;
    int health;
};

int main ()
{
    int action;

    cout << "Enter how much new player: \n";
    cin >> action;

    People *my_people = new People[action];

    for (int i = 0; i < action; i++)
    {
        cout << "NAme: \n";
        cin >> my_people[i].name;
        cout << "health int \n";
        cin >> my_people[i].health;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < action; i++)
    {
        cout << "result: \n";
        cout << my_people[i].name << '\n' <<
                my_people[i].health << '\n';
    }

    delete[] my_people;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `main(); //Выходим в начало программы` НЕТ! вы делаете `main` рекурсивным со всеми вытекающими. В общем уберите эту строку. Добавьте обычный цикл в самое начало `main` и закройте его где-то в конце.

Comment: В таком случае, я думаю, что лучше будет всё вынести в отдельные функции и работать внутри них. Обмениваться данными между ними с помощью глобальных переменных.

Comment: я конечно не против глобальных переменных, но сейчас прибегут и расскажут почему это плохо и почему так не стоит делать :) так что подумайте ещё раз, стоит ли. Вообще глобальность в современных языках не поощряется.

Comment: Вопрос, простой как 2х2: Почему не поощряется? :)

Comment: Ещё я заметил, что другие программисты создают массив не из самой структуры, а из полей структуры. Например, из соседнего вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/668399/%d0%a1%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%a1-%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8?rq=1 Какая разница между массивом из структуры и массивом из полей структуры?

Comment: даже не знаю как ответить. Смыслом слишком коротко. Если в 2 словах - массив структур - несколько структур подряд. а если внутри - то этот массив будет в КАЖДОМ объекте структуры.

Comment: В таком случае, мне видимо нужно поискать о представлении массивов структур в памяти. Иначе на словах пока трудно "увидеть" разницу. :)

Comment: @Любитель, на счет глобальных переменных. Суть в том, что в разработке очень важно управлять сложностью всей логики программы. Если у вас куски кода хорошо отгорожены(инкапсулированы) от других частей программы, то вы можете сосредоточиться на каком-то небольшом фрагменте, и держать только его в голове. В случае с глобальными переменными вам нужно держать в голове всю программу, так как глобальную переменную может изменить кто угодно, где угодно. Если у вас программа из 100 строк, то проблем особых не будет, а вот на 10 000 мозг начнет кипеть.

Comment: В общем, на данный момент у меня пока всё равно не укладывается в голове порядок работы правильный. Если вынести переменную структуры в в начало программы, то позже, во время работы программы можно наткнуться на исключение bad_alloc. Что логично. Поскольку в самом начале программы не известно, сколько именно новых контактов будет добавлено. Нужно найти другой способ работы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил эту задачу следующим образом:
Моя основная проблема заключалась в том, что я не мог понять, как именно организовать работу с динамической памятью таким образом, что бы новые данные не удаляли предыдущие, как это всё выводить на экран и так далее.

По не опытности, я делал слишком много динамических массивов для операции копирования (старые, затем "склеивание" старых плюс новых записей и так далее). Путался сам и делал из простого - сложное. Изучив учебник Эллайна глубже, я открыл для себя такую вещь, как файловый поток, я наконец понял, для чего (и как работает) нужны передачи аргументов в функции.

По порядку:

- Если пользователь добавляет новые контакты, то сперва программа спрашивает, сколько их будет. Потом заполняются поля (динамической)структуры. После всего, файловый поток записывает данные структуры на диск.
- Если пользователь хочет посмотреть список контактов, то вызывается отдельная функция, которая открывает файловый поток, снова заполняет массив из (динамической) структуры, откуда потом забираются данные для вывода в консоль.
- Приятный бонус, который я тоже наконец понял - vector<> =)

Всем спасибо за ответы, я решил свой вопрос.

Comment: Очень странно при попытке просмотра списка контактов - считывать данные с диска, когда можно считывать из вектора в программе. Дисковые операции в сотни или тысячи раз медленнее работы с памятью. Понятно, что в Вашем тестовом задание, на малых количествах данных это не заметно, но в целом этого нужно избегать.

Comment: Я понимаю, все эти возможные ограничения, с которыми могу столкнуться в случае с файловым потоком. На данный момент, я правда начинаю путаться, когда имею дело с большим количеством динамических массивов. Поэтому, пока решил задачу так :)

Comment: В любом случае, я доволен тем, что смог расширить некоторые другие границы. Читая теорию, я фактически не понимал разницу между обычным массивом и вектором. Плюс, я захватил тему xml в qt. Это интересная тема для меня)

Answer (score 0):

```
//Добавляем данные в динамическую структуру. Так как неизвестно сколько по 
 факту будет новых пользователей
People *my_people = new People[NewContact];
```

Данные добавляете в массив my_people;

```
People My_people[pins];
for (int i = 0; i < pins; i++)
{
    cout << "Name: " << My_people[i].UName << '\n' <<
                    "Job: " << My_people[i].UJob << '\n' <<
                    "Phone number: " << My_people[i].UPhone << '\n';
}
```

Объявили пустой массив My_people на pins элементов и сразу пытаетесь вывести значения. Это разные массивы, они ничего не знаю друг о друге.

Как и в втором Вашем варианте, необходимо в начале функции main() объявить

```
People *my_people = new People[size];
```

и работать только с ним.

По поводу этого кода

```
    int NewContact;
    string name;
    string job;
    int PN;

    //Спрашиваем, сколько будет новых контактов
    cout << "How many new contacts do you want to add?\n";
    cin >> NewContact;

    //Заполняем поля в цикле столько раз, сколько указано указано в переменной выше
    for (int i = 0; i < NewContact; i++)
    {
        cout << "Name new contact: \n";
        cin >> name;

        cout << "As whom does " << name << " work?\n";
        cin >>  job;

        cout << name << " phone number: \n";
        cin >> PN;

        pins = pins + 1; //Увеличиваем на 1 количество записей.
    }

    //Добавляем данные в динамическую структуру. Так как неизвестно сколько по факту будет новых пользователей
    People *my_people = new People[NewContact];

    //Копируем по одном введённую выше в структуру.
    for (int i = 0; i < pins; i++)
    {
        my_people[i].UName = name;
        my_people[i].UJob = job;
        my_people[i].UPhone = PN;
    }
    delete[] my_people;
```

Вы в цикле записываете значения в переменные string name; string job; int PN, каждый раз затирая старые значения. А затем в отдельном цикле добавляете экземпляры класса People в массив с одинаковыми значениями.
Вот возможное решение:

```
int NewContact;
string name;
string job;
int PN;

//Спрашиваем, сколько будет новых контактов
cout << "How many new contacts do you want to add?\n";
cin >> NewContact;

People *my_people = new People[NewContact];

//Заполняем поля в цикле столько раз, сколько указано указано в переменной выше
for (int i = 0; i < NewContact; i++)
{
    cout << "Name new contact: \n";
    cin >> name;

    cout << "As whom does " << name << " work?\n";
    cin >>  job;

    cout << name << " phone number: \n";
    cin >> PN;

    pins = pins + 1; //Увеличиваем на 1 количество записей.

    my_people[i].UName = name;
    my_people[i].UJob = job;
    my_people[i].UPhone = PN;
}
```

Comment: мне кажется, я начинаю понимать ещё кое какую важную вещь, когда прочитал слово "затираю". В идеале, нужно куда то поместить уже имеющийся контакты, что бы не произошло их "затирания". Поработать с новыми, потом вернуть копию на месте, а затем дополнить новыми. То есть, поместить в конец.